# Using Asp.Net Core Identity in Web Api application that uses JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, identity, bearer-token, asp.net-core-identity

What is the proper way to configure and use Asp.Net Core Identity in Web Api application?

I've looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), but looks like it demonstrates cookie based authentication in View-based MVC Web apps, not Web Apis. I know in Asp.Net Core the MVC Web Apps and the Web Api applications follow the same middleware pipeline, but what if I don't want cookie based authentication?

Does it make sense to use Identity at all if I want to use JWT bearer token for authentication? I've walked through a few tutorials which use JWT bearer token for authentication and also uses Identity. I've explored the sample codes, and looks like they are using Identity solely to take advantage of the built-in `UserManager` and `RoleManager` classes for the ease they provide with data access.

Do you use Asp.Net Core Identity in your Web Api application when you are using bearer token for authentication? If yes, what purposes does it serve in your application?